# SQL DB Version without attaching

Tags: sql-server

Random question, but I was wondering if there is a way to determining the SQL server version of a database before attaching it (i.e. whilst in a folder on the network).

The reason I ask is because we receive extremely large databases that take ages to attach only to then fail because they are not the correct version.

I was hoping there might be a tip to save time.

Many Thanks

Comment: try [restore headeronly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi SMor, thanks for the suggestion. It appears that most of the files we get are .mdf and not .bak so I can't get this to work.